# How can i run a part of a script as a different user?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, su

```
#!/bin/ksh
(some code)
Log=~/my.log
chown USER1 filename

su - USER1 -c "
date | tee -a ${Log} 2>&1; 
cd /blah/blah
if [ SOMECONDITION ]
then
sh ./somescript.ksh > logfile
fi
exit" | tee -a ${Log} 2>&1;
```

The script tends to stop when it swicthes to USER1 and then it executes again when we have to exit manually.

Comment: See [Why can't we execute a list of commands as different user without sudo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86778/22565)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas This is only relevant if the script isn't running as root. Given that the script calls `chown`, it is highly likely to be running as root.

Comment: @Gilles, my answers there are for the case where the script is running as root.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that the script stops at the "su" command because it's prompting for a password and not getting one.

As often multiple solutions for that :)

Instead of "su" use "sudo" which has the -S switch to accept a password from standard input:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S -u USER1 sh -c "...
```

Alternatively move that section of your application/script that needs to run as a different user to a helper application. You can then avoid scripting with a stored clear text password (which has some security concerns)  by using the set-uid and set-gid on that helper application:

```
chown USER1.GRP1 helperapp
chmod 6755 helperapp
```

The risk you run with this is that now anyone on the system can run helperapp as USER1. 
Instead of using set-uid/gid you can use configure sudo to allow a specific user to run het helperapp as USER1 without a password prompt (this requires admin/root priviliges):

```
# /etc/sudoers
# Allow USER2 to run helperapp as USER1 without prompting for a password
USER2 ALL=(USER1) NOPASSWD:/path/to/helperapp
```

your code can then look something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
(some code)
Log=~/my.log
chown USER1 filename

sudo -u USER1  /path/to/helperapp |  tee -a ${Log} 2>&1;
```

None of this was tested and use at your own peril...

Comment: You can add TCPMUX to the list.

Comment: This is only relevant if the script isn't running as root. Given that the script calls `chown`, it is highly likely to be running as root.

Comment: yes it runs as root

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running `su -`, you are telling `su` to run a login shell. A login shell ignored its `-c` argument and reads commands interactively instead. The solution is to not pass `-`.

If you want to read the target user's startup file, do that explicitly.

```
su - USER1 <<EOF
date
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
…
EOF 2>&1 | tee -a -- "$LOG"
```